# Is there a way to build a (v0) Versioned Transaction that references only some of it's accounts from an Address Lookup Table?

Tags: versionedtransactions

As there is a one slot warmup for newly appended addresses to Address Lookup Tables, is there a way to partially use an Address Lookup Table, and then pass any accounts that aren't active in the lookup table in that slot separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since the warmup is only the current slot, it is likely you have in memory the previous `AddressLookupTableAccount` objects before extending, as a result you can use that to compile and it should work completely fine when calling `MessageV0.compile` as those addresses aren't yet in the table objects.

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/ceeec9d6254c9f5f410ed23200fc3d1a28eb6bb8/web3.js/src/message/v0.ts#L187